# repository.cloudera.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: maven, hadoop, hbase, cloudera

My pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
      <version>0.94.10</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <repositories>
    <repository>
         <id>cloudera</id>
         <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
```

In my browser, I can download hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.1.jar from https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.1/ without issues, But when I try to build my project using maven, I've got this error:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:pom:2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.1 
from/to cloudera (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/):
repository.cloudera.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known: Unknown host
repository.cloudera.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

==**udpate**==

I can ping https://repository.cloudera.com

```
└ $ ping https://repository.cloudera.com
PING https://repository.cloudera.com (220.250.64.27): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 220.250.64.27: icmp_seq=0 ttl=238 time=45.730 ms
```

Not able to ping repository.cloudera.com

```
└ $ ping repository.cloudera.com
PING repository.cloudera.com (75.101.141.93): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

Comment: Can you download org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:pom:2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.1 from Cloudera in your browser?

Comment: @zsxwing yes, I can download it without any issues.

Comment: hm. do you have any proxy configured in the browser?

Comment: @JBaruch, no, I don't think so.Strange enough, I can open it via all browers, chrome, firefox without proxy, but I can't even ping repository.cloudera.com. Btw, I am using a mac :(

Comment: Yes, `nodename nor servname provided, or not known` is a DNS  issue. Maybe http://superuser.com/ is a better match for this question...

Comment: Please try running maven with -X switch to enable full debug logging as said. That might give you a better picture, if nothing's helping.